# The Column not in sequence in Power Bi

Tags: sql, powerbi

The column I categorize using **Case-When** as **Year_Category** which consist only year 2016,2017,2018, 2019 and 2020.
The SQL code as below

```
CASE WHEN Year(STARTED) = '2016' THEN '2016'
          WHEN Year(STARTED) = '2017' THEN '2017'
WHEN Year(STARTED) = '2018' THEN '2018'
WHEN Year(STARTED) = '2019' THEN '2019'
WHEN Year(STARTED) = '2017' THEN '2020'
END AS YEARS_CAT
```

The question is, when I drag the the **Year_Category** at Power Bi designer, the Year_Category not in sequence like image below.

[powerbi image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9zxK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Either convert that column into whole number or create another column that will act as a sorting column for Text Year column

Sample code that will help in sorting the column:

```
Text Year Sort =
VAR CurrentDate = Dates[Date] -- Date in the row context
VAR YearCurrentDate =
    YEAR ( CurrentDate )
VAR MaxDate =
    MAX ( Dates[Date] )
VAR MinDate =
    MIN ( Dates[Date] )
VAR YearMinDate =
    YEAR ( MinDate )
VAR YearMaxDate =
    YEAR ( MaxDate )
VAR YearGap = YearMaxDate - YearMinDate
VAR Result =
    1 + YearGap
        - ABS ( YearCurrentDate - YearMaxDate )
RETURN
    Result
```